# Sums of dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, math

I have a dataframe, that has a varying number of columns depending on my dataset. I want a function that will add up the combinations of these columns and append these new 'summed columns' to the existing dataframe.

For example if I have 3 columns, I want 3 more columns with 1 summed with 2, 1 summed with 3 and 3 summed with 2.

Much obliged.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can use [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) combined with [`pandas.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
from itertools import combinations

out = pd.concat({f'{a}+{b}': df[a]+df[b] for a,b in combinations(df, 2)}, axis=1)
```

Example:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame({k: np.random.randint(0, 10, 5) for k in list('ABC')})

from itertools import combinations
out = pd.concat({f'{a}+{b}': df[a]+df[b] for a,b in combinations(df, 2)}, axis=1)

print(df.join(out))
```

output:

```
   A  B  C  A+B  A+C  B+C
0  5  9  7   14   12   16
1  0  3  6    3    6    9
2  3  5  8    8   11   13
3  3  2  8    5   11   10
4  7  4  1   11    8    5
```